# NodeMouseClick event doesn't work correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i use a treeview to display files and folders like Windows Explorer. it has a NodeMouseClick event but sometimes when i click +, this event doesn't fire.

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {            
        MessageBox.Show("node mouse click");            
    }
```

can anyone explain for me why ? and how to know whenever i click + ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might rather want to have a look at

[TreeView.AfterExpand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterexpand.aspx)

> Occurs after the tree node is
>   expanded.

or

[TreeView.BeforeExpand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeexpand.aspx)

> Occurs before the tree node is
>   expanded.